# Uninstalling ROS and installing it back

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 (64-bit). I had previously installed ros-cturtle but didn't use it much. Since a new version of ROS is available, I wanted to upgrade my version. Unsure on how to go about doing it, I did something stupid and deleted the ros directory on my machine, along with all references to ros I could find with locate (in the hope I could do a fresh install of diamondback). However, after this I installed diamondback and found that roscd is still looking for cturtle:

```
roscd:cd:4: no such file or directory: /opt/ros/cturtle/ros
```

I am not sure if roscd is a "binary" that I could find and delete or where its getting this information from. I use Z-shell and I have removed references of ROS_ROOT from my .zshrc. I removed diamondback using sudo apt-get remove ros-diamondback-ros as I want to build and install from source. But before that, I want to get rid of this problem, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
S.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9658/uninstalling-ros-and-installing-it-back/) by [Sudarshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/291/sudarshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2011-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you still have some references to the old ROS in your .zshrc or somewhere.  The roscd command is defined in roszsh.

1. Look for references to setup.zsh that are still cturtle related
2. Look for lines like:

   source $ROS_ROOT/tools/rosbash/roszsh
3. Look for definitions of $ROS_ROOT that are still pointing at cturtle.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudarshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/291/sudarshan/) on 2011-04-06**:
It's weired. I restarted my machine and roscd no longer exist. I was able to install diamondback without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't have to remove the old version of ROS to start using a new one. Multiple versions can happily be installed next to each other. E.g. the cturtle version is installed in /opt/ros/cturtle, and the diamondback version is installed in /opt/ros/diamondback. You can switch between versions by setting your environment:

source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash

If you do want to remove a version of ROS, you should use the apt tools instead of manually removing files:

sudo apt-get remove ros-cturtle-ros

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-04-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try this peeps                     sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove ros-kinetic-*

---

Originally posted by [Amine_Frei](https://answers.ros.org/users/28460/amine_frei/) with karma: 21 on 2016-11-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1